# php oop code syntax, unused instances

Tags: php

I'm trying to accomplish the following syntax in my code:

```
$data = new Data();
$user = $data -> user -> get(1);
$product = $data -> product -> get(1);
```

By using:

```
class Data {

    public $user = null;
    public $product = null;
    public $a = null;
    ...

    function __construct() {           
        this -> user = new User();
        this -> product = new Product();
        this -> a = new A();
        ...
    }

}
```

The problem with the code is that I will have lots of unused instances inside the data class because I will not use them all in specific scenarios. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Simple. Don't use that code. Instead look up factories and singletons.

Comment: Either overload with `__get()`, or change to a design where there's no need for instantiating unused objects. Factories are quite OK, beware of global scope in Singletons, and actually, if a `Data` class needs a `User` or `Product`, you'd usually make sure with Dependency Injection that the class has them if you want them there.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I'm using the same code with LS11 small change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very basic level, you can do something like this, you define a getter for the user property, and the object only gets instantiated when you call it for the first time.

```
class Data {

    protected $user = null;

    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->user === null) {
            $this->user = new User();
        }
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use aggregation, which means that you pass an object into the class, that way the class is getting either null or the object and you save resources by not initializing everything at once. [Here's a decent post about it](http://www.emmanuelndayiragije.com/view-aggregating-objects-within-php5) (not mine).

It's basically this:

```
class Test {
  public $a = '';

  public function __construct($object) {
    $this->a = $object;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say you could try something like this:

```
class ThisOne{

    protected $user = null;

    public function user()
    {
        if ($this->user === null) {
            $this->user = new User();
        }
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

The getter only gives you an object the first time it is called!